# What is the use/purpose of struct map_segment

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, data

I was looking through source code of the Linux kernel (version v2.6.38) and I stumbled upon an undefined `struct map_segment` defined in `exec_domain`:

```c
struct exec_domain {
    const char      *name;      /* name of the execdomain */
    handler_t       handler;    /* handler for syscalls */
    unsigned char       pers_low;   /* lowest personality */
    unsigned char       pers_high;  /* highest personality */
    unsigned long       *signal_map;    /* signal mapping */
    unsigned long       *signal_invmap; /* reverse signal mapping */
    struct map_segment  *err_map;   /* error mapping */
    struct map_segment  *socktype_map;  /* socket type mapping */
    struct map_segment  *sockopt_map;   /* socket option mapping */
    struct map_segment  *af_map;    /* address family mapping */
    struct module       *module;    /* module context of the ed. */
    struct exec_domain  *next;      /* linked list (internal) */
};
```

`exec_domain` is used in `thread_info`.

My questions:

1. Where is `map_segment` defined? (What are all the member variables? My best guess so far is it points to some low level architecture dependant structure)
2. What is the purpose of it and where is it used? (In the comments, it says it can be used in socket type mapping, but again im not too familiar with this. What even is a socket type mapping?)

Any Information regarding this subject would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. `struct map_segment` isn’t defined anywhere in the kernel, at least not in version 2.6.38. That’s fine in C — as long as the members’ contents are never needed, all the compiler needs to know is the size of the field, and since that’s a pointer, it’s just the size of a pointer.
2. The `struct map_segment` fields are never used. I imagine their purpose is to allow personalities to define mappings — probably [`errno`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) values in `err_map`, [socket types](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/socket.2.html) in `socktype_map`, [socket options](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/socket.7.html) in `sockopt_map`, and [address families](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/address_families.7.html) in `af_map`.

The `exec_domain` data structure [was removed in release 4.1 of the kernel](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=9058f3b326dbe8cd2ebea7f3cfe367b0d101039b).